# Function with reference type return

Tags: c++, reference

I am confused about the difference between

```
int& refReturn(int &ref){ //return type int&
   ref++;
   return ref;
}

int main(){
   int num1 = 1;
   int num2 = refReturn(num1);
}
```

and

```
int refReturn(int &ref){ //return type int
   ref++;
   return ref;
}

int main(){
   int num1 = 1;
   int num2 = refReturn(num1);
}
```

It seems like both results in num2 not referencing num1. So why would people prefer one over the other?

Comment: The type of `num2` is `int`, not `int &`, so of course it doesn't reference anything else. The function has nothing to do with that. Just like `int a = 1; int b = a;`: `b` is an independent variable.

Comment: Try with `int & num2 = ...`. You will find that the first version compiles and `num2` is a reference to `num1`, while the second version no longer compiles (unless you are using MSVC, which allows some things the C++ standard forbids).

Comment: In this example? You wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between returning a reference (`int&`) and a non-reference (`int`) is that the non-reference is returning a *copy*, the returning of a reference is *returning an existing item*.

The function:

```
int refReturn(int &ref){ //return type int
   ref++;
   return ref;
}
```

will increment the variable `ref` (the actual contents will be modified because you passed by reference), then return a copy of the incremented value.

The function:

```
int& refReturn(int &ref){ //return type int
   ref++;
   return ref;
}
```

will increment the variable `ref` (the actual contents will be modified because you passed by reference), then return the variable so that it may be modified (no copies returned).

The above function allows you to perform the following:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a = 6;
  refReturn(a) = 27;
  cout << "Value of a is: " << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the above program, the `refReturn` function will increment `a` by 1 and return a reference to the variable.  The assignment operator will assign 27 to the reference, which is `a`.  Thus the output should be 27 for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are basically the same. There is a kind of conversion from reference-to-int into int. It's like:

```
int num1=1;
int &ref=num1;
int num2=static_cast<int>(++ref);
```

The different is that in the first case the conversion from reference-to-int into int (if there is such conversion) happened in main function. While in the second case the conversion is happened in the refReturn function.

And yes num2 is not reference to num1. num2 is an ordinary variable. If you want num2 referencing num1 then you need to change num2 into a reference variable like this:

```
int &num2=refReturn(num1);
```

note: this is applied to the first refReturn function.